# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty }\left ( 1-\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \right )^{2n}$ diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

could anyone help me figure out whether this infinite series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\left ( 1-\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \right )^{2n}$$
diverges?

I've tried using Cauchy's and d'Alembert's limit tests but both gave the result 1. I've also tried the necessary condition for convergence, but 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left ( 1-\frac{\ln(n)}{n} \right )^{2n}=0$$

Comment: You can use $1+x \leqslant e^{x}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Bigl( 1 - \frac{\log n}{n} \Bigr)^{2n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \biggl(\exp\Bigl( -\frac{\log n}{n} \Bigr)\biggr)^{2n} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp( - 2\log n ) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty.$$

Comment: Thank you! Really elegant and simple, I don't understand how I could have missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Cauchy Condensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), we get the series. 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^nf(2^n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( 1 - \frac{n \log 2}{2^n}\right)^{2^{n+1}} 2^n \tag{1}$$
Here we can use [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test), 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left( 1 - \frac{n \log 2}{2^n}\right)^{2^{n+1}} 2^n} = \frac 1 2 \tag{2}$$
to argue that $(1)$ converges which implies the convergence of out original series.
To evaluate the limit $(2)$, 
$$2 \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{n \log 2}{2^n}\right)^{\frac{2^n}{n \log 2}2 \log 2} = 2 e^{- 2\log 2} = \frac 1 2$$

Comment: It seems that your method of thinking like mine;-)

Comment: @user63181 yep!! I was wondering if you missed $2n$ for $2^n$ down in denominator??

Comment: Thank you very much. Also for making me familiar with Cauchy Condensation.

Comment: @Dominik you are welcome :) usually Cauchy Condensation is weapon of choice for $\log$

Answer (score 2):

This is convergent.

Hint (not a concrete proof):
$$
(1-\frac{\ln n}{n})^{\frac{n}{\ln n} 2\ln n}\sim e^{-2\ln n}=\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$